# Failed test in protractor stops the execution for rest test cases

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am running the protractor Suite (spec file having multiple test cases), If any test case fails, protractor does not continue with the next test case execution and all the rest of test cases also fail.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

Upon failure on any test case, protractor should continue with next test case execution.

I used "Protractor-Fail-Fast" Npm package to stop the rest test case execution if any test case fail. But ideally I am not looking for the same.

But this will not help me!

[Just for reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86c38be8-7c95-4afa-82b0-d0dfa0d31c62/how-to-continue-with-ordered-test-execution-with-the-rest-test-cases-on-failure-of-one-test-case?forum=vsunittest): In Visual Studio MS test, If I created ordered test (same as Spec file in protractor having multiple test cases) and then set test setting like "*continue on failure*", ordered test execution will continue even if some test case failed.

I am looking for a similar test setting or any solution for protractor.

Comment: Improved formatting and punctuation

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't want to stop all tests run just stop using `Protractor-Fail-Fast` library? Protractor tests run till the end by default even if some of the tests are failed.

Comment: Consider one scenario. i just wanted to click one button say "Save".I have correct selector for the same the.I am going tom click on "Save" button but unfortunately button n itself is not present. in that case i am getting Unhanded promise rejections error and execution going to stop.  Note: I have handled promises correctly using asyn and await.

Answer (score 0):

set  `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` in config file as following:

```
/**
* If set, Protractor will ignore uncaught exceptions instead of exiting
* without an error code. The exceptions will still be logged as warnings.
*/
ignoreUncaughtExceptions?: boolean;
```

you can get above description from [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L562)

```
export.config = {
   ...
   ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true
}
```

Comment: what is purpose of ignoreUncaughtExceptions. could you please elaborate??